# "Game server" or "games server"

Tags: grammatical-number

This question can seem trivial but I'm not a native English speaker. I'm hosting a server which hosts games and I was wondering: is it called a *game server* or a *games server*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest *game server* on the basis of other similar constructions such as *file server* or *database server*, where the object being "served" is singular rather than plural. Wikipedia [agrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_server).

Comment: [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=games+server%2Cgame+server&year_start=1980&year_end=2004&corpus=0&smoothing=3) agrees.